# don't get POST variables after submit Multipart/form-data

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

A part on my page is responsible for multiple picture uploads, it worked for a while but it is not working anymore.
I'm using a WampServer Version 3.1.7 64bit and testing on localhost.

I have tried accepting and sending datas via ajax instead of html submit, but i didn't get datas on php side either, but on client side i had all datas before sending ( `FormData()` ).

**HTML part:**

```
<div class="div_shadow_here">
    <form id="gallery_data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[" formid "]; ?>" />
        <table class="news_table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="name_col">Gallery name:</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="input_news" id="gallery_title" type="text" name="gallery_title" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="name_col">Picture(s):</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="input_news" id="news_picture_path" type="file" name="picture_path[]" multiple />
                    <label id="label_for_input" for="picture_path">Select picture(s)</label><span id="uploadState"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <div id="img_container"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button class="print_button hidden_a" type="submit" name="login" id="save_news" form="gallery_data">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**PHP part for testing:**

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo '<script>console.log("Not empty")</script>';
    if (isset($_POST['formid'])) {
        echo '<script>console.log("'.$_POST['formid'].
        '")</script>';
    }
    if (isset($_POST['gallery_title'])) {
        echo '<script>console.log("'.$_POST['gallery_title'].
        '")</script>';
    }
    if (isset($_FILES['picture_path']['name'])) {
        echo '<script>console.log("'.count($_FILES['picture_path']['name']).
        '")</script>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<script>console.log("Empty")</script>';
}
```

I get `Notice: Undefined index: gallery_title..` errors without `isset($_POST['gallery_title'])` testing (same for all other input fields).

**Ajax for testing:**

```
$('body').on('click', '#save_news', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);

    for (var key of formData.keys()) {
        console.log(key);
    }

    for (var value of formData.values()) {
        console.log(value);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'galleryupload.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Data Uploaded: " + data);
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Show the AJAX code.

Comment: You have a spaces inside $_SESSION[" formid "], this work but it's a very bad practice. Your code work if you put an "action" inside form. but put your AJAX code and maybe we can help you

Comment: So the error suggests there was nothing posted with that name, do `var_dump($_POST);` in your php to see whats actually being received

Comment: Your code works fine in my laptop...sorry, the error should be in other part of your code.
(By the way, you have a label script inside alert...I guess you are made test XD )

Comment: There are no spaces in my real code, but HTML formatter put those there, so it shouldn't be the problem. The code worked for more then 1 year without ajax. Just submitting the form by the button. But it's not working anymore, and i don't know why. This is why i have tried to use ajax instead of HTML submit, but the same problem occurs (PHP side didn't get the datas, says Undefined index: ..).

Comment: maybe here is the problem ` var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]); `  and you are send other form,if you try only this part of code all run fine.

Comment: `data: $('gallery_data').serialize(),`

Comment: I cut all of the rest of my code out, and testing on that way, same result. Maybe some Wampserver bug?!